# Can I host a SandstoneDB app on www.Seasidehosting.st?

Tags: hosting, seaside, object-oriented-database

Did someone ever manage to make a seasidehosting-hosted web application cooperate with SandstoneDb? It seems that they disallow creating of subdirectories, which is important for SandstoneDb. Am I wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't personally tried sandstoneDB on seasidehosting.st, but I know that it is possible to create subdirectories. Just stay below `FileDirectory default`. The [Pier CMS](http://www.piercms.com) also uses a file structure to store data and it perfectly works on seasidehosting.st.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i talked to the sandstoneDB inventor AND to the seasidehosting.st support staff. They are both fantastically friendly and helpful. (They did not communicate to each other, but I think I got it figured out by now.

So, it turns out that you CAN create files and directories on seasidehosting.st. But not the way sandstoneDB does it. Here's the general workaround:  http://lists.squeakfoundation.org/pipermail/seaside/2006-August/008746.html.

So, I think I will modify SandstoneDB to create its files this way and I hope that Ramon will put the change into his release.

cheers,

Niko

*Edit*: This is becoming a major operation. I've read this thread now and it is not the solution to my problems. I am not even completely certain what my problem is.

I think this is going to be a little more of a problem and I will need something like Smalltalk-shell access on the server. This basically means that I will have to switchc my app to development mode on the server. It's a little scary. But I really see no other way. I've uploaded enough files of 20 MB each. Time for the big guns. But not today. On the weekend.